# Filtering a select query to return only records that don't have a corresponding record in a joined table

Tags: php, sql

```
TABLE GROUP
group_id | user_id
   1          1

TABLE USERS
user_id | fullname
   1      Juan dela Cruz 
   2      Maria
```

I’m displaying the result in my table `users` using a foreach loop but what I want is 
when the `user_id` in my table `group` exists I don’t want it to display anymore. How can i achieve that? I know that I need to cross table but don’t know where to start also I’m thinking using an `INNER JOIN` but it will just merge the same `user_id` into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM group)
```

Comment: I don't think that calling table 'group' is a good idea since it's an SQL command (GROUP BY). user_groups would be better, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. Also about your concern actually I have a prefix in all my tables. -Dean

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct u.user_id, u.fullname
from USERS u
left outer join GROUP g on u.user_id = g.user_id
where g.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id <> <ID>
```